# How to connect to Google Drive and create Google Docs with meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, google-api

My web app uses `Meteor.loginWithGoogle` with `requestPermissions: ['email']` to login users.

I would like to connect to Google Drive of some users on their request and create some Google Docs.

### 1. Getting permission

How can I get the permission to access the Google Drive of the user?

Should I call the function `Meteor.loginWithGoogle` with more permissions? Maybe with something like :

`requestPermissions: ['email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']` ?

Should I do this every time I want to access the Google Drive of the user ?

### 2. Listing Google Docs and creating new

How can I list and create new Google Docs?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

1/ Separate permissions with Strings like this:

```
Meteor.loginWithGoogle({
  forceApprovalPrompt: true,
  requestOfflineToken: true,
  requestPermissions: ['email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']);
```

Use `requestOfflineToken` to be able to access it even if the user is not connected.

2/ Use the Google api. with a HTTP.call() or use a package like https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-google-api

Comment: Thanks ! I managed to set some permissions and get some data with the API. But do you know if there is a way to do the same without using loginWithGoogle ? (for example, if a user logged in with password and if I then do loginWithGoogle it will create a second user...)